# Firebase Deploy Not updating the content

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Earlier i have deployed my project on reactJs using Firebase , and recently i have made changes to it and deployed it again  using " firebase deploy" but the resulted URL is still showing the previous content but not the updated content !! what can i do? Any suggestions?

done with hard reload/using incognito window/changed my project too on firebase/updated Js files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to build before you deployed? Try running `npm run build` followed by `firebase deploy`. Hopefully that fixes your problem :)

Comment: Did that work? Please accept it as an answer if so :)

Comment: HAHA, Such a small thing and it made me mad...